# frida.TimedOutError: unexpectedly timed out while initializing suspended process

Tags: ios, jailbreak, cydia, frida, sslpinning

**Describe the bug**

Timeout occurred on objection explore

**To Reproduce**
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Run command `objection --gadget "com.apple.AppStore" explore`

**Evidence / Logs / Screenshots**

```
Using USB device `iPhone`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/objection", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/objection/console/cli.py", line 114, in explore
    agent.inject()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/objection/utils/agent.py", line 202, in inject
    session = self.get_session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/objection/utils/agent.py", line 169, in get_session
    self.session = self.device.attach(self.spawned_pid)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/frida/core.py", line 76, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/frida/core.py", line 800, in attach
    return Session(self._impl.attach(self._pid_of(target), **kwargs))  # type: ignore
frida.TimedOutError: unexpectedly timed out while initializing suspended process
```

**Environment (please complete the following information):**

1. Device: iPhone 7
2. OS: 15.3.1
3. Frida Version: 16.0.2
4. Objection Version: 1.11.0

Comment: Your phone is jailbroken?

Comment: yes, it is. Tried `frida-ps -U` and works.

Comment: AFAIR `frida-ps -U` also works on non-jailbroken phones as it used the debugger from the DeveloperDiskImage. At the beginning better try not to start `com.apple.AppStore` instead try to attach to it when it is running, that should work.

Comment: @Robert What do you mean when you say "attach to it when it is running"? Could you please elaborate it?

Comment: You can start an app if it is not running using Frida or you can attach to an existing process. These are the two options Frida has. The latter is usually the easier task on iOS.

Comment: I got similar error when I run it `objection -g pid explore` like: `type: ignore
frida.TransportError: timeout was reached`

Comment: @Robert it worked on non Apple-silicon MacOS. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Robert solved with pid choice. There are two important things here:

1. Don't use Apple-Slicon(m1/m2) MacOS
2. Use process-id instead of process-name. `objection -g pid explore`

Comment: using process id instead of process-name fixed my frida issue (Failed to spawn: unexpectedly timed out while waiting for app to launch ).